# Importing pictures from XML doc into Flash using Actionscript3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am having troubles with understanding how to get a picture in an XML file to import into Flash using actionscript3. Here is the code I have so far:

```
stop();

import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.*;

var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
myXML.load("graphics.xml");
myXML.onLoad = function(success) {
if (success) {
var myImage = myXML.firstChild.childNodes;
for (i=0; i<myImage.length; i++) {
var imageNumber = i+1;
var imageName = myImage[i].attributes.title;
var imageURL = myImage[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
trace ("My image number "+imageNumber+" is titled "+imageName+" and its URL is "+imageURL+".")
}
}
};
```

This is the errors I get:

Scene 1, Layer 'Content', Frame 3, Line 14, Column 6    1120: Access of undefined property i.

Scene 1, Layer 'Content', Frame 3, Line 15, Column 19   1120: Access of undefined property i.

Scene 1, Layer 'Content', Frame 3, Line 16, Column 25   1120: Access of undefined property i.

Scene 1, Layer 'Content', Frame 3, Line 17, Column 24   1120: Access of undefined property i.

Scene 1, Layer 'Content', Frame 3, Line 14, Column 29   1120: Access of undefined property i.

Scene 1, Layer 'Content', Frame 3, Line 14, Column 11   1120: Access of undefined property i.

I will be very grateful for a solution to this as I am trying to get to grips with Actionscript3. Thankyou for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare the variable.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<myImage.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that solved those problems. Now it is coming up with another problem: Scene 1, Layer 'Content', Frame 3, Line 11, Column 7 Warning: 3594: load is not a recognized method of the dynamic class XML. and Scene 1, Layer 'Content', Frame 3, Line 12, Column 7 Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onLoad event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'load', callback_handler).

Comment: @Mike1211 you're actually using **AS2** code. The **AS3** compiler will not accept it. Try an [**`AS3 tutorial`**](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/) and see if it helps you.